# Read particular sheet from Google sheets in r

Tags: r, google-sheets

I am trying to make r to read particular sheet from google sheets. I am using:

```
library(googlesheets4)

gs4_auth(email = ...)
mydata8 <- read_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/.....',
sheet='worked hours per month')
```

But this returns me a mistake:
Error in `gargle::response_process()`:
! Client error: (400) FAILED_PRECONDITION
• Request can not be executed in the current system state, such as deleting a non-empty directory.
• This operation is not supported for this document

What I am doing wrong and what would be the correct way of getting the data from particular google sheet if there are several of them...

Answer (score 5):

The issue is, that the file I have is saved on drive in xls format. When file is resaved as a google sheet then everything works fine